# Mapbox map display 2 map instead of 1

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mapbox, react-hooks, mapbox-gl-js

Im new in reactjs and mapbox and i have an issue, the map that I apply,it display twice after I scale it small. pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrGce.jpg

and how can i make the layout like this pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmSOf.jpg

newsfeed component

```
const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      display: "flex"
    },
    drawer: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      flexShrink: 0,
      opacity: 0.7
    },
    drawerPaper: {
      width: drawerWidth
    },
  }));

  export default function Newsfeed(){
    const classes = useStyles();
      return(
          <>
            <Drawer
            className={classes.drawer}
            variant="permanent"
             classes={{
                paper: classes.drawerPaper
            }}
            anchor="right"
            >
                <Divider />
                <List>{mainListItems}</List>
                <Divider />
                <List>{secondaryListItems}</List>
            </Drawer>         
          </>
      )
  }
```

dashboard:

```
export default function Dashboard(){
  return(
    <>
    <div>
      <Appbar />
      <Map />
      <Newsfeed />     
    </div>

    </>
  );
}
```

Map component
    export default function Map() {
      //API called

```
  //set the default lat lon
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    latitude: 3.0858333333333334,
    longitude: 101.58666666666666,
    zoom: 12,
    bearing: 0,
    pitch: 0
  });

const [fleetDetail, setFleetDetail] = useState(null)

  return (
    <div>
      <MapGL
        {...viewport}
        width="1000px"
        height="1000px"
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10"
        onViewportChange={setViewport}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
      >

      </MapGL>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: The problem doesn't seems to be here. Can you share the Newsfeed code?

Comment: Im new in stackover flow, i have edit the map component code to newsfeed code. thank you very much :)

Comment: Thanks for adding that. But i never said to remove the Map code.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i have add the map code